# rspec newb does not understand how to satisfy "before" method

Tags: ruby, rspec

Newb here...just getting my feet with with rspec and have a question with the following:

```
describe Song do

  before do
     @song = Song.new
  end

  describe 'title' do
    it 'should capitalize the first letter' do
      @song.title = "lucky"
      @song.title.should == "Lucky"
    end
end
```

I'm not sure how to satisfy the "before do ....end"
I see it being written in many tutorials and rspec examples but i'm stil lost on how to satisfy with ruby code so that it will pass. thanks

Comment: What errors do you find you're getting?  Also, for more info on before hooks, check [the RSpec documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-2/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks) for some good examples on how they're used (`before(:each)` is equivalent just `before`).

Comment: `before` is not there to test anything. It's simply a block used to setup the test for all the later `it` steps. You don't need to satisfy anything. The actual testing is done inside the `it` steps.

Comment: thanks for the input...i seem to be lost at how to tacke the test "@song.title ="

Comment: Also you have a spelling error in your test: `title = "luky"` but you test for `"Lucky"`. `"luky" != "Lucky"` so your test will not pass.

Comment: all of the previous tutorials...the test was straight forward example: "title = 'lucky' "    without the "@song"

Comment: Ok. After your edit the test looks better. If your `Song` model is working correctly the test should pass now.

Answer (score 4):

RSpec can be confusing at first, since there are always many valid ways to achieve the same goal. That is why I would recommend you get [The Rspec Book](http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book) instead of (or before) going through *"many tutorials and examples"*.

I could come up easily with eight different ways for this single test (see the code sample below), and you could mix and match parts of them even more, resulting in even more different ways to solve the same problem.

This is why I think getting a basic understanding of RSpec principles is necessary before you are able to work through examples and tutorials - every example will look slightly different, but if you have the basics down, you will easily be able to see what each example does.

```
require "rspec"

class Song
  def title=(title)
    @title = title
  end

  def title
    @title.capitalize
  end
end

describe Song do
  before { @song = Song.new }

  describe "#title" do
    it "should capitalize the first letter" do
      @song.title = "lucky"
      @song.title.should == "Lucky"
    end
  end
end

describe Song do
  describe "#title" do
    it "should capitalize the first letter" do
      song = Song.new
      song.title = "lucky"
      song.title.should == "Lucky"
    end
  end
end

describe Song do
  let(:song) { Song.new }

  describe "#title" do
    before { song.title = "lucky" }

    it "should capitalize the first letter" do
      song.title.should == "Lucky"
    end
  end
end

describe Song do
  let(:song)  { Song.new }
  subject     { song }

  before { song.title = "lucky" }

  its(:title) { should == "Lucky" }
end

describe Song do
  let(:song) { Song.new }

  describe "#title" do
    before { song.title = "lucky" }

    context "capitalization of the first letter" do
      subject { song.title }
      it { should == "Lucky" }
    end
  end
end

describe Song do
  context "#title" do
    before { subject.title = "lucky" }
    its(:title) { should == "Lucky" }
  end
end

RSpec::Matchers.define :be_capitalized do
  match do |actual|
    actual.capitalize == actual
  end
end

describe Song do
  context "#title" do
    before { subject.title = "lucky" }
    its(:title) { should be_capitalized }
  end
end

describe Song do
  let(:song) { Song.new }

  context "#title" do
    subject { song.title }
    before { song.title = "lucky" }
    it { should be_capitalized }
  end
end
```